# Excel/Sheets Formula for "If addition of two times is between 00:00 and 7 am display time in red, if not display time in black"

Tags: google-sheets, time, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

I'm trying to reference multiple time additions and subtractions. Essentially I've got Cell A that is a date and time and constantly changing and Cell B that is a time that changes too. Then Cell C that displays Cell A + Cell B. I want to make if Cell C is a time between midnight and 7 am display the time in Red font. If not display the time in Black font.

Here is an example Sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Qjr2JzC42z3sxqH7Rz4BSMsAMv1LIAZH3gES9fYeY0g/edit?usp=sharing  . The date and times on the left must add a time on the right, but then also check to see if its a specific time (date doesn't matter) and if it's between 00:00 and 7:00 then show the specific date and time  in red otherwise black. I think  the answer may have something to do with conditional rules and I found [this](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/questions/cond_format1_2010.php) article indicating changing font colors in excel but the formula comparing specific times I'm stuck on.

I've tried to make an example formula in a cell without conditional rules to check to see if I can make it work by doing `=IF(AND(C5>=MIN(P5:P47),C5<=MAX(P5:P47)),"YES","NO")` but thats not working. I also came across this formula which may help `=AND(val>MIN(NUM1,NUM2),val<MAX(NUM1,NUM2))` but am unsure at this point.

---EDIT---

Figured it out using a conditional format `=AND(HOUR($C5)>=0,HOUR($C5)<=7)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually just Figured it out with Conditional Format `=AND(HOUR($C5)>=0,HOUR($C5)<=7)`

Answer (score 0):

Add A1 and B1 in C1 and then use Conditional formatting with a custom formula in C1.

`=TIME(HOUR(C1), MINUTE(C1), SECOND(C1))<0.29`

You can choose the custom format to be a red font.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=TIMEVALUE(C1)<=TIMEVALUE("7:00:00")
```

[image: 0]

Comment: So that's extremely close to what I want, the only problem is if I format the 'C' cells to show day of the week as well then it breaks the conditional formatting. Would I need I need to create a condition for every day of the week to be an exception?

Comment: Actually just figured it out with a conditional format =AND(HOUR($C5)>=0,HOUR($C5)<=7)